# Linker synonym to 'As a result'

Tags: synonyms

What synonym linker to 'As a result' can work here?

> The busiest part of the whole center was the hydrochannel.
> Investigations and tests were conducted 24 hours a day. **As a result,**
> many floatplanes, speedboats, submarines, and torpedoes were improved
> there.

Comment: Reasonable research is expected. From [Thesaurus.com](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/as%20a%20result): therefore / consequently / as a consequence / hence / in consequence / so

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consequently, therefore, ergo, thus, thusly.

Answer (score 0):

...Accordingly...

...Rapid technological advancement of various materiel including: floatplanes, speedboats, submarines, and torpedoes ensued.

if i were editor, i'd even like to paraphrase the preceding sentence to something like:

...hydrochannel, the venue of ceaseless research and development.  Rapid advancements in materiel technology such as: floatplanes, speedboats, submarines, and torpedoes ensued.

Comment: Where do you get those additional sentences?! Please focus on the question alone.